# Using linear mixed models to model nested data

Tags: r, independence

I divided participants into different pairs according to their language proficiency score, and now I ask participants in different pairs to have conversations, so every participant now have a pair ID (e.g., pair 1, 2, 3...). I want to investigate how the pause frequency in participants' individual speech in the conversation predicts their language proficiency scores. So I used a linear mixed model with pair ID as a random effect, the pause frequency as fixed effects, and the language proficiency score as the dependent variable. I used the linear mixed model to address the non-independent data.

formula in R:

```
Language proficiency score~pause frequency+pause length+(1|pair ID)
```

The model runs successfully. However, I found the marginal R squared value is pretty small, and it seems large variance is explained by the random effect. Is this because I had paired participants according to their proficiency score and then included pair ID as a random effect in the model to predict their language proficiency score (the random effect is not really random)? How can I solve this problem?